# JS to Java callbacks sometimes happen on a different thread

Tags: jxbrowser

We have JavaScript to Java callbacks that we handle and we noticed that sometimes, that starts to happen on a new thread. (After some amount of time/sleeping computer).

Is there anyway to make it consistently use the same thread for JavaScript to Java callbacks?

JXBrowser 6.9

Comment: Maybe you can clarify why it's important to get calls on the same thread?

Answer (score 0):

This is a designed behavior in JxBrowser. The idea to use different threads during processing JavaScript-Java callbacks is to support reentrancy (JavaScript sync calls Java -> Java sync calls JavaScript) and avoid deadlocks. There's no way to force JxBrowser to use a single thread in this case.